# counting digts in c++ using log10

Tags: c++, logarithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, temp, rem, digits=0, sum=0;
    cout << "Enter a armstrong number: ";
    cin >> n;
    temp = n;
    digits = (int)log10(n) + 1;

    while (n != 0) {
        rem = n % 10;
        sum = sum + pow(rem, digits);
        n = n / 10;
    }

    if (temp == sum) {
        cout << "yes";
    }
    else {
        cout << "not";
    }
}
```

How does the " digits = (int)log10(n) + 1; " line actually calculates the digits?
can anyone explain?

Comment: In C++, include `<cmath>` rather than `<math.h>`.

Comment: Do you know what the logarithms (to base 10) are for values like 10, 100, 1000, 10000? Do you know them for 50, 600, 7000? Do you know what happens if you cast those values into an `int`? What else do you need explained?

Comment: Apart from that, using floating point functions and then expecting integer results (even after casting) can have some nasty surprises for you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm explains this property of logarithms at the very beginning.

Comment: *"How does the " `digits = (int)log10(n) + 1;` " line actually calculates the digits?..."* This is **more of a math question instead of programming question**. https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was confused about the (int) part from the line . @JasonLiam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.

Logarithms are basically "exponents in reverse." Log10(100) is `2.0`, as 10 to the second power is 100.

Cast to `'int` and add one to that are you get `3`, which is the number of digits.